# Re-using prepared statements for Sqlite in Golang

Tags: sqlite, go, sqlx

I'm using `sqlx` and `modernc.org/sqlite` (https://pkg.go.dev/modernc.org/sqlite) to insert 500K rows in a Sqlite database.

The performance is already reasonable, execution time is below a minute; but I'm hoping to improve it as I'm inserting thousand batches of 500K rows (which takes me a day on a m7g.2xlarge EC2 instance)

According to https://jmoiron.github.io/sqlx/, a NamedStmt is a representation of a prepared statement with support for named parameters.

I have a `*sqlx.NamedStmt` that is created by

```golang
    db.prepInsertEbsSnapshotStmt, err = db.tx.PrepareNamed(sql)
```

which I assumed would prepare the statement. Yet calling the call graph (generated by pprof) indicated that calling the statement below will still generate a call to the `(*conn).prepareV2`

```golang
db.prepInsertEbsSnapshotStmt.Exec(snap)
```

[image]

My question is : Is there a way to re-use a prepared statement using `sqlx` & `modernc.org/sqlite` as it seems that the SQL statement is prepared each time a SQL statement is executed which defeats the purpose of prepared statement

Comment: I have no idea what `db.tx.` means but `tx` looks like a transaction. May it be that transaction-specific prepared statements "disappear" along with a transaction? I mean, what if you try to create an [MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367019/720999) which would first try to do an absolutely dumb example w/o any transactions and verify preparing works as it's supposed to be, and then you add transactions in the mix and see what happens?

Comment: @kostix - Your are correct `db.tx` is transaction object. But it shouldn't disappear along with the transaction as as I only commit at the very end (bulk insert).